# About PIC programming

Tags: microcontroller, pic, programming, pic16f877a

[image: errors in my code.]Hi friends iam new to PIC programming , I'm coding my pic in mikroC pro , please help me out.. iam attaching my file with this!the code i want is message from transceiver should receiver and check whether the message is ON or OFF then pic should function on my output accordingly!

Comment: Those red lines indicate Errors

Comment: I know those are errors, but can u please verify my code and guide me how to do?

Comment: Without knowing your environment, it's difficult, but at first glance you have no includes so the compiler has no way to find ANSEL etc.

Comment: Please [*don't post code as screenshot*](http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The compiler doesn't know what the variables `TRISABITS` etc are, which means you didn't tell the compiler about them. This is usually done by including the appropriate file given by Microchip. For example, in my header files I have:

```
#include <p18f47j13.h>  // For a PIC18F47J13
```

It might be easier to use MPLAB X from Microchip and use their project wizard to start your project. MPLAB X will make sure that the mentioned include file is there.

Comment: ok thank you so much!  MPLAB X i will check it once

Comment: It's not problem at all. Please mark answers as "Accepted", and upvote if you are happy with it. :)

Answer (score 1):

use MPLABx + xc8 compiler (both are for free).
Know include `xc.h` header in every source file.
That should work.